# Where does WordPress store plugin (enabled/disabled) status for multisite?

Tags: plugins, database, options, location-search

A recent update to one of the plugins I use broke my multisite blog and in the process of debugging it, all of the plugins got disabled. Now I have to try to figure out which plugins used to be enabled, but that's a big chore for various reasons.

I've probably got at least one backup since the last time I toggled plugin, but I don't know where WordPress stores plugin state information for a multisite blog.

I tried dumping the whole WordPress database to try to search for the plugin state settings, but the thing is too much of a monster to manually search through, especially since most search terms return too many results to be practical.

Does anybody know where WordPress stores the state of plugins? Does it store them in every sub-blog's settings or is there a master one? What about network-enabled plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. It's in the `active_sitewide_plugins` value of the `wordpress_sitemeta` table.

Comment: (Sorry correct answer, you'll have to wait two days to be eligible to be selected, but I'll probably forget by then. )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `active_plugins` from the wordpress Options API if your site is not Multi-site wordpress site.

You can run it as:

```
add_action("plugins_loaded", function(){
           $active_plugins = get_option("active_plugins", []);
           
           echo "<pre>";
           print_r( $active_plugins );
           echo "</pre>";
}
```

and it will print out all active plugins on your site.

Comment: It is a multi-site, but this is useful to know. (It might be easier to just query the value directly from  MySQL).